# What does “<>” exactly mean in “echo <> temp.txt”?

Tags: linux, bash

#### Non existing file

```
$ ls file_not_exists.txt
ls: cannot access file_not_exists.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo <> file_not_exists.txt

$ ls file_not_exists.txt 
file_not_exists.txt
$ cat file_not_exists.txt
$
```

#### File with content

```
$ cat temp.txt 
asdf
$ echo temp.txt 
temp.txt
$ echo <> temp.txt 

$ cat temp.txt 
asdf
```

If the file does not exist, `echo <> file_not_exists.txt` will create a new file. So I think `>` works (redirecting the empty output into a newly created file). But if there is something in the file (like `temp.txt`), why it is not emptied by `echo <> temp.txt`?

Comment: it doesn't actually mean anything. that command should have been flagged as an error, but since linux is designed to try its hardest and fail safely, it executes anyway, even thought it probably shouldn't have. instead, it ignores the input operator < and executes the rest of the line and creates a file, because thats what cat does when you tell it to output to a file that doesn't exist. it won't overwrite a file with nothing however, as a safety consideration. otherwise it would be trivial to overwrite files on accident with a misfiring script.

Comment: Because `<`with void input will (a)void an operand `>` followed by it, so the `<>` means nothing and affects nothing - they "kill" each other when there's nothing between them.

Comment: If you've asked about it before but got unsatisfactory answers, don't ask about it again, but edit your previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

```
[j]<>filename
  #  Open file "filename" for reading and writing,
  #+ and assign file descriptor "j" to it.
  #  If "filename" does not exist, create it.
  #  If file descriptor "j" is not specified, default to fd 0, stdin.
  #
  #  An application of this is writing at a specified place in a file. 
  echo 1234567890 > File    # Write string to "File".
  exec 3<> File             # Open "File" and assign fd 3 to it.
  read -n 4 <&3             # Read only 4 characters.
  echo -n . >&3             # Write a decimal point there.
  exec 3>&-                 # Close fd 3.
  cat File                  # ==> 1234.67890
  #  Random access, by golly.
```

So,

```
echo <> temp.txt
```

Will create `temp.txt` if it does not exist, and print an empty line. That is all. It is equivalent to:

```
touch temp.txt && echo
```

---

Note, *most* programs will not expect the STDIN file descriptor (0) to be open for writing, so in *most* cases, the following will be roughly equivalent:

```
command <> file
command 0<> file
touch file && command < file
```

And since *most* programs will not expect STDOUT to be open for reading, the following are usually roughly equivalent:

```
command 1<> file
command > file
```

And for STDERR:

```
command 2<> file
command &2> file
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo <> temp.txt` causes the file `temp.txt` to be opened for both reading *and* writing on file descriptor `0` (stdin).

From `man bash`:

> Opening File Descriptors for Reading and Writing
>          The redirection operator
>
> ```
>           [n]<>word
>
>    causes the file whose name is the expansion of word to be
>    opened for both reading and writing on file descriptor n,
>    or on file descriptor 0 if n is not  specified.   If  the
>    file does not exist, it is created.
> ```